# Find out in what position my thread landed in a ReentrantLock

Tags: java, concurrency, locks

I want to find out in which position of the LockinQueue of a ReentrantLock my Thread landed in? is there some magic lock which returns the position in the queue when calling lock.lock()? Or does anyone know how to realize that?
Thanks in advance
Thomas

Answer (score 2):

@toto has pointed out to me that it does provide an estimate using getQueueLength().  You could take the length before or after acquiring the lock depending why you want to know the length.

The queue is lock less so whatever the position was, it could be incorrect by the time the value has been estimated, never mind by the time the method has returned. Generally you are not interesting in the position as you should structure your code so it is rarely waiting for the lock.

Perhaps you could indicate why you are interested....

Comment: `ReentrantLock.getQueueLength()` "Returns an _estimate_ of the number of threads waiting to acquire this lock."